# Microsoft Word - Alphabetical sorting?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I suspect that what I am looking for may not exist - but it would make my life easier if it does.

A long list of items (in a bibliography) in Microsoft Word 2007. Any way to get Office to sort them alphabetically instead of having to do it manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, found the answer myself... Sort option in the paragraph group... much to my surprise...

Comment: Makes me wonder though; my references are always sorted automatically. Or are you typing all that stuff by hand?